# Issue while using hbase java client while puting data in database

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am testing the hbase . i am using a standalone one without hadoop. i used the version hbase 0.90.6 the code worked fine and i upgraded to latest version 0.94.0 it fails and gives this exception while i try to put datas in table.
Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: DoNotRetryIOException: 1 time, servers with issues: xxxx:36601, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:776)
    at com.hhase.Hbase.main(Hbase.java:22)
```

I am using the below code.

```
package com.hhase;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class Hbase {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Configuration hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HTable table = new HTable(hConf, "myLittleHBaseTable");
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"),
                Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"), Bytes.toBytes("Some"));
        table.put(put);


    }
}
```

Library used

```
commons-cli-1.2.jar            hadoop-core-1.0.2.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar          hbase-0.94.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  httpclient-4.1.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar  httpcore-4.1.4.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar     log4j-1.2.16.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar             protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar           slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar      slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
commons-net-1.4.1.jar          stax-api-1.0.1.jar
guava-r09.jar                  zookeeper-3.4.3.jar
```

Comment: set ur configuration file to                            Configuration hConf =HBaseConfiguration.create();conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","xxx.xx.xxxx");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","xxxx");

Answer (score 4):

I encountered same error while inserting data into the HBase.
In my case, it was due to incorrect column family name.

Please refer to [this conversation](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201207.mbox/%3CBLU0-SMTP132588C868959138B6469798FD20@phx.gbl%3E).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.